# Split template string on line breaks ignoring literal \n

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I have some textual data in multiple lines, stored in an ES6 template string. Any line may contain a literal `\n` string.
Example:

```
`line1
same\nline2
line3`
```

I want to split that string into an array of lines, where each line originates from a line of the template string, without splitting at a literal `\n` within a line. So my expected / wanted result was a JavaScript array looking like this: `["line1", "same\nline2", "line3"]`.

When looking at the example below, this obviously doesn't happen when simply splitting using a regexp for line breaks (`/\n/`).

So, is this possible at all? Am I missing / misunderstanding something on how template strings work?

```js
const lines = `line1
same\nline2
line3`.split(/\n/);

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(lines)
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Problem is, a `\n` within a template literal is parsed *identically* to a literal linebreak - try `console.log`ging the string before splitting it. Maybe you wanted `\\n` in the template literal instead?

Comment: Having `\\n` in the template literal would have been nice, but I exported the data from an SQL database. The output is in multiple lines with some `\n` inbetween. I now escaped these line breaks in a text editor. My hope was to skip an intermediary step.

Comment: @alex3683 Your SQL database did create JS code? I think you should add the appropriate escaping to that export function.

Comment: @Bergi No, not the JS code. Just the data in tab-separated values style. I just copy it out of the SQL manager and wanted to drop it into a template string in my JavaScript function.

Comment: @alex3683 Yes, just this "copy out from the SQL result and place it in the JS code" process. If possible, you should automate that process and  use a proper escaping mechanism, such as [making the SQL engine output JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (that's just the first search result I got).

Comment: @Bergi You're totally right. My plan is to automate this. I just needed some quick'n'dirty way to access and process the data and this is what I came up with. ;-) Anyways, I thought this would be good to know for the future when working with template strings. So nonetheless a helpful stackoverflow question, at least for me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) tag on your template literal:

```
const lines = (String.raw `line1
same\nline2
line3`).split(/\n/);

console.log(lines);
```

Comment: Great. That's just what I hoped existed! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

`\n` is treated as a new line and regex will always match it. In your string you can escape `\n` like:

```
`line1
same\\nline2
line3`
```

Splitting by `\n` will give now:

```
 ["line1", "same\nline2", "line3"]
```

Beware that now `\n` is just a string, not a new line - but you can map this array and replace it to the *real* new line.

```
["line1", "same\nline2", "line3"].map(value => value.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"))
```

Comment: That's what I feared would be the case. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry, changed the accepted answer, since that unexpectedly solves my problem.